# HTC Desire S-Off

Tags: adb, s-off

My HTC Desire is stuck in a boot loop:

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/52571/htc-desire-boot-loop

I am trying to set S-Off so that I can use the Windows version of ADB and delete some apps/data off the phone memory.

I don't want to wipe all the data off the phone memory and reset back to factory settings.

I have tried using Revolutionary on two separate computers however, it just remains on the 'waiting for phone to connect' message.  I have tried the phone in Fastbot mode and Recovery.

I can't remember if the phone has USB debug enabled or not as I cannot boot into Android to check?